# find coordinate of intersection between circle and line (define by 2 points)

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to get the coordinates of the intersection of a circle with a line.

Here is a drawing to summarize.

[image: circles]

Comment: Algebraically, determine the equation of each circle and the line. Then find the points by setting the appropriate equations equal to one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point can be calculated as $$(x_1 + r\cos \theta, y_1 - r \sin \theta)$$ where $$\theta = \tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{y_1 - y_2}{x_2 - x_1}\bigg)$$
Similarly, you can find the other point as $$(x_2 - r \cos \theta, y_2 + r \sin \theta)$$

(I am assuming the other circle also has radius $r$)

Comment: I’d suggest expressing $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ directly in terms of the endpoint coordinates instead of introducing the (admittedly small) complication of sign ambiguity in the arctangent. I.e., use a unit direction vector for the line segment.